Found the best match
I have a challange to resolve it, I have a a data base with 10 million of registers basically names of a person to assign the gender given the name, the register have several issues like spelling mistakes, names without spaces, or spaces between the letters, and words without sense for example: 'XYZTU','K A REN', 'GUADAULPE','ARMANDOEDUARDO','KENIAMARIA','RO DRI G O','FRANCIS CO', (some cases are correctly write). the challange is impute the gender based on a rules, by the other hand, I have a databse with names as a references split by genders, I've implemented two strategies, first remove all spaces on a string, then I used rapidfuzz and faiss to found the best match, rapidfuzz return similarity but only by small k-mers of a words:
process.extractOne('KENIAMARIA', all_names, scorer=fuzz.WRatio)

output:
('NIA', 90.0, 76)

The  name 'KENIA' and 'MARIA' are present database of reference
I try to limit the search using embbedings to pass a rapidfuzz
def find_candidates_with_faiss(query, top_k=5):
    """
    Find top-k nearest neighbors for the query using Faiss.
    """
    query_embedding = vectorizer.transform([query]).toarray().astype(np.float32)
    distances, indices = faiss_index.search(query_embedding, top_k)
    return [(all_names[i], distances[0][j]) for j, i in enumerate(indices[0])]


find_candidates_with_faiss('KENIAMARIA')

output
[('MARIAMA', 0.54681545),
 ('KENIA', 0.5820314),
 ('MARIAM', 0.59808457),
 ('NIAMA', 0.6583518),
 ('ARIAM', 0.715029)]


but name MARIA is't found
My question is how can found the reference names in a compund name, or found the best match computationally efficient.
